# Skip songs in winamp based on minimum stars rating

Tags: winamp, playback

Is there a Winamp function/plugin that will skip playback of songs that have rating lower than a set minimum of stars?

Comment: I don't use Winamp, but in iTunes you would do it like this: You create a smart playlist which only should contain song with the given minimum rating. iTunes refreshes that playlist automatically. I think you find something simmilar for winamp. http://www.google.com/search?q=winamp+smart+playlist

Comment: I do something similar to what @TimBüthe mentions, except in foobar2000. I'd be very surprised if winamp did not support playlisting by arbitrary information.

Comment: What I want is a plugin that will play those files (if I didn't want them, they wouldn't be in my library at all), but when shuffling just has a strong bias towards songs I've rated higher.

Comment: ML advanced view will not update dynamically current playlist, when a song is rated. I'm looking for something that will work on current playlist.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no way to automatically skip the playback of those songs, there is a way to generate a smart play list to perform this action for you.  To do it, right click "Local Media", and then click "Add Smart View...".

Go to Advanced Mode, and then enter:

> `rating >= 2`

You can use the >= or > operator.  The above will generate a dynamic playlist (updates each time you add/remove music from the Winamp Media Library), with only songs rated at least 2 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a playlist with your >= 2 rated songs duplicated a few times.  Shuffle will be statistically more likely to encounter higher rated songs.